# How do I create 2 graphs in one plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

So far I have created two graphs separately

**1.**

```
library(tidyverse)

# going to to create my X axis which will be time 
x<- c(1950:1991)

# Create my Y values, which is the mean for every year that the summary command will show

summary(Data_Set_For_Earsten_Political_Block)

y <- c(61.00,61.44,62.23,63.01,63.75,64.47,65.15,65.79,66.40,66.96,67.50,67.96,68.40,68.77,69.11,69.40,69.66,69.90,70.11,70.29,70.49,70.65,70.81,70.93,71.05,71.17,71.27,71.37,71.47,71.56,71.67,71.79,71.93,72.08,72.23,72.39,72.50,72.58,72.65,72.67,72.67,72.66)

# Make Plot:

plot(x,y, xlab = "Year", ylab = "Average Life Expectancy For Females", main = "Life Expectancy For Females in The Eastern Political Block", type = "o", col="red", pch =20, lwd=2)
```

**2.**

```
z <-c(70.13,70.33,70.73,71.10,71.44,71.78,72.10,72.39,72.66,72.91,73.17,73.38,73.60,73.78,73.96,74.14,74.32,74.50,74.68,74.87,75.08,75.28,75.52,75.78,76.03,76.34,76.62,76.90,77.14,77.41,77.62,77.83,78.03,78.21,78.40,78.58,78.73,78.93,79.08,79.24,79.41,79.54)

# Creating plot: 

plot(x,z, xlab = "Year", zlab = "Average Life Expectancy For Females", main = "Life Expectancy For Females in The Western Political Block", type = "o", col="blue", pch =20, lwd=2)
```

How do I combine these two graphs into one plot so that I can visually compare them?

Comment: Use `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` before the first plot. Examples and more advanced techniques can be found here: https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

Comment: using your current workflow / base r plotting, you can add further data using `points`: `plot(x,y, col="red", ylim=range(c(y,z))) ; points(x,z, col="blue")`, with a quick hack on setting the yaxis limits for both sets of data

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @r2evans, the easiest way is to set `par(mfrow = c(2,1))`.

```r
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(x,y, xlab = "Year", ylab = "Average Life Expectancy For Females", main = "Life Expectancy For Females in The Eastern Political Block", type = "o", col="red", pch =20, lwd=2)
plot(x,z, xlab = "Year", zlab = "Average Life Expectancy For Females", main = "Life Expectancy For Females in The Western Political Block", type = "o", col="blue", pch =20, lwd=2)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can combine values for these plot into one dataframe by using `tidyverse` and plot them using `ggplot2`:

```r
df = data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-x, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = Value, color = Variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Average Life Expectancy For Females") + 
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("y","z"), labels = c("Eastern", "Western"))
```

[image]

And if you really prefer to separate plots you can add the argument of `facet_wrap` like this:

```r
labels = c(y = "Eastern", z = "Western")
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-x, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = Value, color = Variable)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("Average Life Expectancy For Females") + 
    scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("y","z"), labels = c("Eastern", "Western")) +
  facet_wrap(.~Variable, labeller = labeller(Variable = labels))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

If you want more example of plotting using `ggplot2`, you can take a look at the [CookBook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I am totally new to R and this was a great help.